# Change MenuItem drawable on user click

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-menu

So I have the following configuration: 
A MenuItem with a selector drawable attached which I want to change based on user click. 
However for some reason I cannot make it work because I cannot find a way to compare the icons(drawables).
My configuration is attached below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_grid_id"
        android:icon="@drawable/grid_option"
        android:title="@string/layout_type"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

Selector is attached bellow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_grid_on_32" 
          android:state_pressed="true" />
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_grid_off_32" /> <!-- default -->
    </selector>
```

Also the onOptionsItemSelected:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.menu_grid_id: {
            //I tried to use getContentState but does not seem to be reliable.   
        }
        default:
            return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you want the new drawable to be applied permanently after the click?

Comment: Yes, I think I found it, I need to use a toggle button. Still reading about it.

Answer (score 0):

I end up answering my own question. Maybe it will help others that have the same problem. 
The idea is relatively simple(if you know it), and it is to use a switch or a toggle button. 
Options menu looks like below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_grid_id"
        android:title="@string/layout_type"
        // that was the difference
        app:actionLayout="@layout/grid_option_layout"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

Now, one can use ToggleButton or Switch. I ended up using ToggleButton. Below one can se the configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/switch_grid"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/grid_option"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn="" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, the drawable selector looks like below(grid_option):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_grid_on_32" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_grid_off_32" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Of course, ic_grid_on and off are some images.